# How to copy a file (image.gif) from my ".jar" to a folder?

Tags: java, image, resources

I've an image in my .jar (program.jar/resources/img/image.gif) and I would want to invoke a methot at the the beggining of my main to copy them to "C:\folder". It should check if the file "C:\folder\image.gif" exist, and, if not, copy it.
I've researched about this topic, but I can't find a way to do it.
This is what I have, and it works... but it creates an empty file (image.gif) whit 0 bytes. It creates **a** file, not **the** file from my .jar.

#### Code:

```
//MyResources.saveResource("/resources/img/image.gif", "C:\folder", "image.gif");
public static void saveResource(String fromFile, String toFolder, String toFile){
    InputStream stream = MyResources.class.getResourceAsStream(fromFile);
    if (stream == null) {
        //send your exception or warning
    }
    OutputStream resStreamOut;
    int readBytes;
    byte[] buffer = new byte [4096];
    try {
        resStreamOut = new FileOutputStream(new File (toFolder + File.separator + toFile));
        while ((readBytes = stream.read(buffer)) != -1){ //LINE 80
            resStreamOut.write (buffer, 0, readBytes); 
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I also get an error (a NullPointerException that explains why the files are empty, but I don't know how o solve):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at
com.github.CrafterPGSV.Chess.Library.MyResources.saveResource(MyResources.java:80)
at com.github.CrafterPGSV.Chess.Library.MyResources.createFolders(MyResources.java:61)
at com.github.CrafterPGSV.Chess.Chess.main(Chess.java:10)
```

My main calls "MyResources.createFolders();" which create the folder if it doesn't exist. At the end of "createFolders", it calls "saveResources(...)" to save the image.

Comment: which one is line 80? Btw. you should close the streams appropriate.

Comment: I would guess `stream` is null. You should implement the `if`-block where this is checked.

Comment: Try accessing your image without a leading /, i.e. "resources/img/image.gif". Also make sure to close your streams, as some of the other folks already advised :-)

Comment: @GyroGearless It works (returns a resource) with both leading `/` or without it

Comment: Thanks for your answers. This is line 80: "resStreamOut.write
(buffer, 0, readBytes);" (insde the While).
I tried without the initial /, but the same. How do I close a stream? (if is with: stream.close(), where should I put it? ). Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's impossible for you to get a NullPointerException at that line: `resStreamOut` is initialized, so is `buffer` and `readBytes`. Clean and rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was the first line of "saveResource()":

```
InputStream stream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(fromFile);
```

Here, "stream" was always null. Here is the way to solve this (using Eclipse):

1. Create a new **package** in **src** (let's call it *resources*).
2. Create a new **folder** in your **package** (let's call it *myPictures*)
3. Create more folders if you want. I'll create a new folder inside *myPictures* and I'll call it *partyPictures*
4. Choose one of your folders and put the images (or whatever) inside. I'll have an image called *imageName.jpg* inside *partyPictures*
5. Then, go to the "Navigator", find your Proyect, and you will see that there is a folder called *bin*. Inside, you should see your packages organised in folders.
6. Look for the folder inside *bin* that has the name of the package you created before (I'll have a folder called *resources*). Inside the folder you'll see a tree-view of the folders inside the package (the ones you created before).
7. Look for your files. (I'll look for *resources/myPictures/partyPictures/imageName.jpg*)
8. If it doesn't exist, **InputStream stream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(fromFile);** will always null. To fix this, copy the image (or whatever file) to the folder.
9. Then use

   ```
   String fromFile = "/resources/myPictures/partyPictures/imageName.jpg";
   InputStream stream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(fromFile);
   ```
10. Change the String **fromFile** to your file's path, and always start with a **/**.
    Your code will look like this:

String fromFile = "/**packageName**/ **folderName**/ **fileName.extension**";

InputStream stream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(fromFile);

## That should be it!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why the other answer got delete, but you need `resStreamOut.close()` after you finish writing.

You need to implement the case when `stream == null` (throw exception presumably).

Also, never catch and swallow errors: `printStackTrace()` is *not* error handling, it is error ignoring.

Comment: Thanks for your advice!

    try {
        resStreamOut = new
FileOutputStream(new File
(toFolder + File.separator +
toFile));

        **if(resStreamOut == null){//SOMETHING}**
        while ((readBytes =
stream.read(buffer)) != -1){
            resStreamOut.write
(buffer, 0, readBytes); //LINE 80
        }

        **resStreamOut.close();**
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated
catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
        something.something();
    }